# Issue with inputs and their labels showing ontop of pop-up mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am creating a popup from my page with an mdDialog, but some content from the original page is showing on top of the mdDialog

Here is a link to how my popup is presenting:

[image]

It looks like  tags and the label for said input tag are all that are rendering on top of my md-dialog

How I am generating my popup:

```
$scope.openTutorial = function(ev){
 $mdDialog.show({
  controller: TutorialController,
  templateUrl: 'partials/tutorial.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true,
  fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen
 });
};

function TutorialController($scope, $mdDialog, DashFactory) {
 $scope.hide = function() {
 $mdDialog.hide();
 };
}
```

Expected result would be any content that is not part of this pop-up to be hidden under the pop-up until it is dismissed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4hid.png)

Comment: link is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, with what I would consider a work around, O added ng-hide onto my troublesome HTML items and then expanded my mdDialog to have onShowing and onRemoving functions to flip some flags to hide the items

```
$scope.openTutorial = function(ev){
  $mdDialog.show({
    onShowing: function(){
      $scope.tutorialOpen = true;
    },
    controller: TutorialController,
    templateUrl: 'partials/tutorial.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
    onRemoving: function(){
      $scope.tutorialOpen = false;
    }
  });
};
```

While this gets the job done, I do believe mdDialog is not working as designed in that it should be on top of these items by default.